# Windows switches automatically to High Performances

Tags: windows-10, performance, temperature, gaming, powersave

Whenever i open a game, also the lighter ones, my pc switches automatically the power plan from "balanced" or "power saving" to "high performance" and it bothers me because the CPU's temperature rises and fans get loud even if it's not really required. 
I noticed that from NitroSense, as i run Windows 10 on an Acer Nitro laptop. 
Any suggestions?

EDIT: Already tried to disable Windows 10's Game mode, I already put the game in "power saving" mode in the Windows's graphics settings and I already tried running the game on both integrated grahics or Nvidia GPU.

Comment: Something in the way your PC manages power plans boosts it automatically to Maximum or Ultimate Performance. You can either try to find what that is, and waste a lot of time doing so, even if it's more rewarding to understand why, or follow the tips here (https://winaero.com/blog/delete-power-plan-windows-10/) and create two shortcuts on your Desktop: one that will delete the Ultimate/Maximum Performance power plan altogether, so that you don't have to endure it popping up uninvited, and one to restore it, should you exceptionally need it after all. I'd go with plan B, but it's your show...

Comment: About disabling [Game Mode](https://www.askvg.com/tip-how-to-disable-game-mode-and-game-bar-in-windows-10/) for particular games or for all